# Text mining in R: How to deal with incomplete and non-sense words in a pdf file when creating a frequency table for most frequent terms?

Tags: r, pdf, text, text-mining

I'm having some troubles making the table for most frequent words in a pdf file because some words appear as incomplete or look "strange". To explain myself better, first the file (in spanish), that can be downloaded from:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/178s_tfbqbXmnxsknxF8DP154_N1DYjgf/view

Second, the code: (Just include your own path and run the code)

```
library(rJava)
library(tm)
library(qdap)
library(tidyverse)
library(pdftools)   
library(stringr)
library(tidytext)
library(stringi)
library(wordcloud)

stop_es <- c(stopwords("es"))   #This is the vector I'll be feeding with additional stopwords

cce <- pdf_text("path/file.pdf")     #Reading the file
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(cce))  #Create corpus

#Cleaning and pre-processing
CCE  <- tm_map(corpus, tolower) %>% 
tm_map(stripWhitespace) %>%
tm_map(removePunctuation) %>% 
tm_map (removeWords, stop_es) %>%
stri_trans_general("Latin-ASCII")   #Remove accents for words in spanish

##Create corpus again. (stri_trans_general has a strange behavior that forces me to make again a corpus) 
CCEGTO <- Corpus(VectorSource(CCE))
```

After previous steps, I explore for most frequent terms with:

```
ft <- freq_terms(CCEGTO, 50, stopwords=stop_es) ##Create the table for most frequent terms
ft
```

That give us the following output (I remove some words to focus my attention on incomplete or "strange" ones)

```
   WORD        FREQ
2  ca           105  ## No idea about this one
3  guanajuato    94
5  vo            86
6  ufb           75   ##¿¿??
9  va            69
10 propuestas    68
11 nivel         64
12 par           58    #For example this one could stand for "parte" or "participacion"
27 ins           42    #This one could stand for "instituto", "institucion" or some else related
28 n             42    #No idea why this simple term appears as a frequent term
30 vos           41
33 numero        40
34 vas           40
35 l             39
38 d             37
39 s             37
42 poli          35  #This one could stand for "policia", "politica", "politicas"
43 vidad         35  #This one could be a bad output for "vida" or maybe for "actividad"
44 cas           34
45 r             34   #Single character...
46 cipacion      33   #This one could be the complement for "parti" in order to form "participacion"
47 i             33
```

Am I missing something on cleaning and pre-processing or maybe is the pdf structure itself that doesn't allow to do a proper text mining job?

Any advice and help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I run a bit of adjusted code with less packages loaded I can create a frequency table which looks normal. Checking the outcome of some functions before going to the next is also useful. See `writeLines` statement to see if everything transforms correctly from the pdf extraction. You might want to use `stri_trans_general` before creating a corpus instead of in the pipeline of the corpus. But then you need to do this to the stopword list as well.

Depending on what you exactly want to do with Spanish text you might want to look into `udpipe`. But try to contain your work with as few packages as possible. So most of the work with `tm` or with any of the other text mining packages like `qdap`, `quanteda`, `tidytext` or `udpipe`.

```
library(tm)
library(dplyr)
library(pdftools)   

cce <- pdf_text("PROPUESTAS GTO 2018 FINAL.pdf")     #Reading the file

# have a look at page 4 output not printed in answer!
writeLines(stringi::stri_trans_general(cce[4], "latin-ascii"))

stop_es <- stopwords("spanish")
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(cce))  #Create corpus

CCE  <- tm_map(corpus, tolower) %>% 
  tm_map(stripWhitespace) %>%
  tm_map(removePunctuation) %>% 
  tm_map (removeWords, stop_es) %>%
  stringi::stri_trans_general("Latin-ASCII")


CCEGTO <- Corpus(VectorSource(CCE))

# create frequency table
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(CCEGTO)
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
df <- data.frame(words = names(colSums(m)), freq = colSums(m))

# filter frequencies 
df %>% 
  filter(freq > 50) %>% 
  arrange(desc(freq))

        words freq
1        fb01  236
2  desarrollo  107
3  guanajuato   94
4    nacional   90
5    problema   73
6      social   69
7  propuestas   68
8       nivel   64
9         par   58
10 ciudadanos   55
11       pais   55
12       leon   53
13        asi   52
14   gobierno   52
```